# In Hebrew, "hummus" means both chickpeas and the dish, what is an example of this sort of thing in English?

Tags: meaning, nouns

A friend and I were eating hummus last night and I pointed out that in Hebrew, the word "hummus" means both the chickpea (an ingredient) and the dish (ground chickpeas with other ingredients).

"Hotdogs" was the first example I came up with.

What are all examples of something like this in English?

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer? You already have an example, what else are you seeking?

Comment: Pasta? Lasagna? Rice? Coffee?

Comment: @KillingTime i think its pretty clear that i am looking for more examples.

Comment: @YosefBaskin coffee is a good one for sure! i thought about pasta and rice, but those dont imply a specific dish really. i dont think lasagna is really it though because it is the dish, not the ingredient.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because requesting open-ended lists is explicitly off-topic. // Technically, I suppose this phenomenon is polysemy-with-metonymy.

Comment: It's not open-ended if there is a finite set.

Comment: Chili - a spice, but also a variety of dishes flavoured with the spice.

Curry - a herb, but also a variety of spiced dishes. 

Mint - a herb,  but also a type of sweet flavoured with the herb.

Quite a few, actually.

Comment: Ooooo chili and mint are good ones!! Curry is interesting because while it is an herb, it is often not included in many "curry" dishes.

Comment: _Lasagne_ (Italian plural) are the sheets of pasta used to make the dish _lasagne al forno_.

Comment: 'It's not open-ended if there is a finite set.' But language is productive.

Comment: Yes! You're right! But now that you mention that, "lasagne al forno" is the full name, so "lasagne" is itself a synecdoche, where "hummus" is not.

Comment: I suppose 'tea' (the leaf of the plant; the infusion) qualifies, but this is certainly metonymy, not synecdoche. // Many Chinese dishes are named after main ingredients (king prawn and cashewnuts / chicken and sweetcorn / duck with ginger and spring onion ... ) but this becomes trivial.

Comment: The 4th of July is both the name of a US holiday and the date of that holiday. Ironically rears its head every few years, when the 4th of July is observed on the 5th of July.

Comment: The 4th of July is not the name of the holiday AFAIK. It is Independence Day, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

"Beans and Rice" or "Rice and Beans" is a relatively common American dish consisting primarily of rice and beans, but also other ingredients (sometimes onions, tomatoes, etc) and various spices.